# Next.js MDX blog post not building due to module not found, runs fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, mdxjs

My Next.js project is failing to build on Vercel.

I have a `BlogAuthor.tsx` file as so:

```
import Avatar from "../../Common/Avatar/Avatar";
import CopyLink from "../../Common/Widgets/CopyLink/CopyLink";

export default function BlogAuthor({
  authorName,
  authorAvatar,
  postDate,
  url,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full lg:px-2">
      <Avatar image={authorAvatar} alt={authorName} />
      <div className="ml-3 flex flex-col">
        <span className="font-semibold">{authorName}</span>
        <time className="text-gray-500" dateTime={postDate}>
          {new Date(postDate).toDateString()}
        </time>
      </div>
      <div className="ml-auto">
        <CopyLink url={url} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

During the build, on `Vercel` I get the following error:

```
> next build
info  - Checking validity of types...
Failed to compile.
./components/Blog/BlogAuthor/BlogAuthor.tsx:1:20
Type error: Cannot find module '../../Common/Avatar/Avatar' or its corresponding type declarations.
> 1 | import Avatar from "../../Common/Avatar/Avatar";
    |                    ^
  2 | import CopyLink from "../../Common/Widgets/CopyLink/CopyLink";
  3 | 
  4 | export default function BlogAuthor({
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

The blog author is used within a `BlogLayout` component. Here is an example of a blog post file:

`how-to-value.mdx`:

```
---
slug: "how-to-value"
title: "Title"
description: "Meta description goes here"
coverImage:
  src: "/img/blog/how-to-value/cover.jpg"
  alt: "Image alt text"
date: "May 11 2022 12:00:00 AM"
author:
  name: "squishyboots"
  avatar: "/img/blog/authors/squishyboots.jpeg"
---

//ALL MARKDOWN STUFF GOES HERE

<BlogLink href="/signup" title="Sign up today!" text="Sign up" />

export default ({ children }) => (
  <BlogLayout meta={meta}>{children}</BlogLayout>
);
```

And finally, here is what my `[slug].tsx` page looks like:

```
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import BlogImage from "@components/Blog/BlogImage/BlogImage";
import BlogLayout from "@components/layouts/BlogLayout/BlogLayout";
import BlogLink from "@components/Blog/BlogLink/BlogLink";
import { HeadOptions } from "@interfaces/interfaces";

const components = {
  BlogImage,
  BlogLayout,
  BlogLink,
};

const BlogPostPage = ({ data, mdxSource, slug }) => {
  const headOptions: HeadOptions = {
    title: data.title,
    description: data.description,
    url: slug,
    image: data.coverImage,
    articleAuthor: data.author,
    date: data.date,
  };

  return (
    <BlogLayout meta={headOptions}>
      <MDXRemote {...mdxSource} components={components} />
    </BlogLayout>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join("_blog-posts"));
  const paths = files.map((filename) => ({
    params: {
      slug: filename.replace(".mdx", ""),
    },
  }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join("_blog-posts", slug + ".mdx"),
    "utf-8"
  );

  const { data: frontMatter, content } = matter(markdownWithMeta);
  const mdxSource = await serialize(content);

  return {
    props: {
      data: frontMatter,
      slug,
      mdxSource,
    },
  };
}

export default BlogPostPage;
```

Therefore, as you can see above I have a `components` object that's passed into `MDXRemote`. It contains components such as `BlogLink`, `BlogLayout` etc.

Do I have to add `Avatar.tsx` to this list as well? It is not used directly in an `.mdx` file.

If so, do I have to include every single component used in this list, even though its just a child of another component? (In this case, `BlogAuthor.tsx`)

If this is the case, won't I just have a giant list of components that need adding to every time I use something new in a blog post? That doesn't seem right to me

Comment: Just to check, have you setup the .mdx support correctly following this doc? https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx